# .htaccess url rewriting

Tags: php, .htaccess

can anybody please tell me the rewrite rule so I can make a URL like this:

```
http://www.mysite.com/index.php?page=directory1/page
what I'm trying to do is remove the "index.php?page=" so i get a
"http://www.mysite.com/directory1/page"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how [Drupal](http://drupal.org) does it; it's very similar to toneplex's example, but it doesn't mess around with extension checking and it adds an extra check on favicon.ico, which many browsers automatically request; this saves an extra hit on your PHP code if you're missing favicon.ico.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are trying to bootstrap everything via the index.php file. So try this out. Any file or directory that doesn't exist will be force through the index.php file.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css)$ /index.php
```

Comment: Given that you've already checked for existing files and directories, why are you doing the additional check on file extensions in the RewriteRule?

Comment: If one of those extensions doesn't exist, it would be sent to the web server 404 and not have to be dealt with by the index.php file

Comment: It doesn't seem particularly useful then; if you're getting lots of hits for those missing files, then you've got other problems to deal with.  The example I added checks favicon.ico, because browsers will automatically request it without it being in your HTML, but the other checks are probably redundant (you can't guess all random extensions, and he might well want to redirect a request that ends in one of those extensions).

Comment: That is the beauty of computing. You can tailor the config to suit your needs. He could take what he likes from both of our answers.